# Keyboard is covering the EditTexts during editing in a dialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-edittext, keyboard, android-dialog

In My App I have `Button` will open a `Dialog` to allow the user to enter some data.

The dialog layout contains a parent `ScrollView` and inside it few `EditTexts` children.

the problem is the `Keyboard` is covering the EditTexts during user edit, so the the user basically can not see what he is typing...

I added

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan|adjustResize"
```

to the `Activity` in the `Manifest` but still same problem. I guess because the problem now is in the dialog itself not in the Parent Activity.

Here is My ScrollView

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/grey_bottom_border"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_display_name" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etItemNameDialog"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="@string/item_name"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="textCapWords"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

and here is a photo how it looks like
[image: keyboard is covering the EditText while editing]

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Set SoftInputMode programmatically for your dialog like this.

```
dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

**[Check also official android documentation.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setSoftInputMode(int))**

Comment: I added it after declaring the dialog widgets and still same problem!